# Matlab: Find ranges in cells for a specific value in a selected row

Tags: matlab

In matlab I have  matrix that has:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
     1 4 5 7 2 1 5 0 2 6;
     1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5]
```

I want to find in 3rd row the starting and end cell that contains 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

For example `ones=1:3`, `twos=4:5', 'threes=5:8', 'fours=9:9` and `fives=10:10`. Is there a way to find this?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood that question right. you want to find the rows that contain only numbers 1-5 in the right order, but how often each number appears is not important? so a row `[1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5]` is just as valid as `[1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5]`?

Comment: you can just do `min(find(x(3,:) == 1) )` and `max(find(x(3,:)==1))` ? and repeat it for 1 to 5?

Comment: @GameOfThrows Yes, that's it thank you! You can write it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `unique` 's ability to record the index of the first/last occurrence to save some bytes and processing time:

```
[C,ia,~] = unique(x(3,:),'first')

C =

 1     2     3     4     5


ia =

 1     4     6     9    10
```

ia gives you the starting indexes.

```
 [C,ib,~] = unique(x(3,:),'last')

C =

 1     2     3     4     5


ib =

 3     5     8     9    10
```

and ib give you the ending indexes.

C gives you the unique numbers you have in the vector merging these together you have almost like a table:

```
 [C;ia;ib]

>> ans =

 1     2     3     4     5
 1     4     6     9    10
 3     5     8     9    10
```

so it reads ones = 1:3, twos =4:5, threes....

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your 3rd column `A = x{i}(3,:)`

```
A = [1     1     1     2     2     3     3     3     4     5]
```

you can simply use

```
[unique(A);find(diff([0 A]));find(diff([A 0]))]

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
     1     4     6     9    10
     3     5     8     9    10
```

and it will give you the starting and ending point of each index in second and third row